# svn - "Once a --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is no longer usable for further work."

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Why is the branch [no longer usable](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the branch no longer usable?

SVNBook 1.7 just a few lines below the line you've quoted tells how to use a keep-alive dance to keep the branch usable.

But that's all irrelevant nowadays with up-to-date Subversion 1.9 and 1.8 clients that support [automatic merges](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate). Read [SVNBook 1.8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html).